# Creating documentation for sub-packages in Workbench

Tags: packages, workbench, documentation

I'd like to create proper documentation for a package of mine, and Workbench in principle provides the tools to do this. However, I've split my package into multiple sub-packages (because I found it easier to maintain the code that way), structured as follows:

```
mainPackage`
           `myPackage`
                     `subPackage1`
                     `subPackage2`
                     `subPackage3`
```

The documentation tools in Workbench are set up in such a way that, out of the box, they only work with one top-layered package. For instance, the *Create symbol pages* button from the *Documentation* tab in the PacletInfo.m editor only looks for symbols within the context \$ApplicationName (which you can set in the *Overview* tab of the PlacletInfo.m editor), and it's not possible for $ApplicationName to have quotes (`).

So my question is: does anyone have a workaround for this? I could merge all my *subPackages* into *myPackage*, but unfortunately it won't be possible to remove the top-layer *mainPackage*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found an acceptable solution.

The first step is to simply structure the application project in Workbench such that the top package `mainPackage` is not there, and merge all the sub-packages into `myPackage`. After building the package and documentation, which then more or less works out of the box, I can then place the package inside the `mainPackage` directory, such that the final directory structure will be

```
$(User)BaseDirectory/
    Applications/
        mainPackage/
            myPackage/
                PacletInfo.m
                code.m
                Kernel/
                    init.m
                Documentation/
                    English/
                        ...
```

However, the problem now is that Mathematica can't find the documentation, because the `myPackage` directory is not directly in `$(User)BaseDirectory` but in the subdirectory `mainPackage`. Thus we need to tell Mathematica to look for subpackages in the directory `mainPackage`. One way to do this is to include the following in the code of `myPackage`:

```
PacletManager`PacletDirectoryAdd[
    FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "mainPackage"}]
];
PacletManager`RebuildPacletData[];
```

This is sufficient for the documentation to show up in the Documentation Center.