# Can a Mathematica Application be inside another Application?

Tags: packages

The file structure of a simple MMA Application can have the form:

```
  MyApplication
    MyApplication.m
    SomeAuxiliarPack.m
    Kernel
      init.m
```

Where `init.m` file have the form:

```
Get["MyApplication`MyApplication`"]
Get["MyApplication`SomeAuxiliarPack`"]
```

Ok.. all nice until here.

The question is. How can I have a SubApplication inside Application, in some way that the SubApplication is independent from the first one, and is initialized together with MyApplication?

Using this structure:

```
  MyApplication
    MyApplication.m
    Kernel
      init.m
    MySubApplication
       MySubApplication.m
       Kernel
         init.m
```

with `init.m` Application as:

```
Get["MyApplication`MyApplication`"]
Get["MyApplication`MySubApplication`"]
Get["MyApplication`SomeAuxiliarPack`"]
```

and `init.m` SubApplication 2 as:

```
Get["MyApplication`MySubApplication`MySubApplication`"]
```

It works, but as you can see, SubApplication init.m has a unnecessary reference for `MyApplication`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I felt this was similar to the issues you have been having and deserved something slightly more then a comment.  This isn't exactly an answer, but I am hopeful to find one.  Please comment if you have any questions or believe it should be pushed to a comment. ) First in `init.m` I have started to define function definitions in `init.nb` precisely like the following.

```
Get[FileNameSplit[If[$InputFileName=="",NotebookFileName[],$InputFileName]][[-3]] <> "`MyApplication`"]
```

Preferably putting the following into `init.m` will import all `.m` files in the main directory.

```
SetDirectory[
  FileNameJoin@
   Drop[FileNameSplit@
     If[$InputFileName == "", 
      NotebookFileName[], $InputFileName], -2]];
Map[Get[FileNameSplit[
       If[$InputFileName == "", 
        NotebookFileName[], $InputFileName]][[-3]] <> "`" <> 
     FileBaseName@# <> "`"] &, 
  DeleteCases[FileNames["*.m"], "PacletInfo.m"]];
```

And `MyApplication.m` would contain the following.

```
BeginPackage[
  FileNameSplit[If[$InputFileName=="",NotebookFileName[],$InputFileName]][[-2]] <> "`MyApplication`"]
(* data *)
EndPackage[]
```

This allows you to simply copy and paste and rename the directory to effectively create a new package.

Now you probably could read back up the directory to determine if the directory above has a `Kernel` directory to successfully generalize and solve the problem above.  I would probably package such into into its own package because it would probably be longer then one line.  If you did this I would advise linking to this [documentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/creating-documentation-for-sub-packages-in-workbench/27056#27056).